# 1st derivatives of $f(\alpha) = \frac{\sin(2\alpha)}{\sin(\alpha+1)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives

Could someone help me out with the following?
I have to get a maximum using the derivative

$$f(\alpha) = \frac{\sin(2\alpha)}{\sin(\alpha+1)}$$

$$f(\alpha) = \sin(2\alpha) \cdot (\sin(\alpha+1))^{-1}$$

$$f'(\alpha) = \sin(2\alpha) \cdot ((\sin(\alpha+1))^{-1})' + (\sin(2\alpha))' \cdot (\sin(\alpha+1))^{-1}$$

$$f'(\alpha) = \sin(2\alpha) \cdot \color{red}{\cdots} + 2 \cos(2\alpha) \cdot (\sin(\alpha+1))^{-1}$$

I can't get any furher then this

Comment: Wait, are your $\alpha$'s supposed to be $x$'s? Otherwise, what are the $\alpha's$?

Comment: @LASV yes, edited ;)

Comment: @Mazzy, edit also the title

Comment: What's the derivative of $\;\sin 2\alpha\;$ ? What the derivative of $\;\sin(\alpha+1)\;$ ? Now apply directly the quotient rule...

Comment: Unfortunately in conventional notation, $\sin^{-1}x$ does not mean the same thing as $(\sin x)^{-1}$, so you're notation is messed up.

Comment: Chain rule. $(\sin(\alpha+1))^{-1} = (g \circ \sin \circ h)(\alpha)$, where $h(\alpha) = \alpha+1$ and $g(u) = \frac{1}{u}$.

Comment: Not only that, @MichaelHardy. In may high schools, at least over here, $\;\sin^{-1}=\arcsin\;$ since that way kids can "understand" better the inverse trigonometric function *with a calculator* (usually a Casio one, here)

Comment: @DanielFischer : Couldn't you have written $(\sin(\alpha+1))^{-1} = (g \circ \sin \circ h)(\alpha)\,{}$, getting the notation right? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I went with the OP's notation. And interpreting $\sin^{-1} x$ as $\frac{1}{\sin x}$ is perfectly legitimate, and not so unusual. After all, when reading $\sin^2 x$ for $(\sin x)^2$, nobody twitches an eye and says that must mean $\sin (\sin x)$ and nothing else, do they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the quotient rule:
$$
\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \right)'=\frac{f'(x)g(x)-f(x)g'(x)}{g(x)^2}
$$
here we have $f(x)=\sin(2x)$ and $g(x)=\sin(x+1)$. So we have
$$
\frac{2\cos(2x)\sin(x+1)-\sin(2x)\cos(x+1)}{\sin^2(x+1)}
$$
If you are looking for a maximum, set this equal to zero and solve.

**EDIT.** As it has been suggested, the intended problem was 
$$
\left(\frac{\sin(2x)}{\sin(x)+1} \right)'
$$
(always a good idea to include parenthesis around function arguments where confusion could arise!)
So that the derivative of the denominator is $\left(\sin(x)+1\right)'=\cos(x)+0=\cos x$. That would give the solution:
$$
\frac{2\cos(2x)\left(\sin(x)+1\right)-\sin(2x)\cos(x)}{\left(\sin(x)+1\right)^2}
$$
which matches their solution.

Comment: I've been told this is incorrect,
it's supposed to be $\cos(\alpha)$ instead of $\cos(\alpha + 1)$ at the end of the top part, could you confirm?

Comment: @Mazzy My solution is correct. The rightmost $\cos(x+1)$ in the numerator came from the derivative of $\sin(x+1)$, which is $\cos(x+1)$ not $\cos(x)$.

Comment: This question was in the national exams, and the answer that you have is the same as in the answersheet except for the part I pointed out. It's very unlikely it's incorrect ?

Comment: @Mazzy The solution you are looking at must have been typed incorrectly. My solution is correct and as been checked with Mathematica.

Comment: Just to add a confirmation that is not needed: the answer is correct. Conceivably they expanded the $\sin(2x)$ as $2\sin x\cos x$, in which case we could get a $\cos x$ at the end of the top part, but we would also have a $2$, and a $\sin x$.

Comment: This is how it's in the sheet:
http://gyazo.com/e06dd7c3c4b9684573cc5346d66e3fe5.png

And this is the answer: http://gyazo.com/c879175bced4fe0d9fdaeba608882360.png Please tell me if the answer in this sheet is incorrect since then that would be a big mistake from their side

Comment: @Mazzy Their solution is incorrect. Moreover, they have also written $(\sin \alpha+1)$ when they meant to write $\sin(\alpha+1)$, a double error! (Triple if you include the same problem with how it is written in the denominator)

Comment: @mathematics2x2life , that's something here, I'll need to make a couple of calls then since it is the official national exams, thanks for that!

Comment: @Mazzy: Don't call! The solution in the link is **correct**. So is the solution above. They are solutions to **different** problems! You stated the problem wrongly. The denominator is supposed to be $\sin\alpha+1$, not $\sin(\alpha+1)$. Good thing too, since with your version solving derivative equal to $0$ could only be done numerically.

Comment: @Mazzy Indeed, if they meant $\sin(\alpha)+1$ rather than $\sin(\alpha+1)$, then indeed the solution is correct. A good reason for when in doubt, include parenthesis around trig arguments! I will amend my answer for that they meant.

Comment: @AndréNicolas \@mathematics2x2life thank you both for putting so much time into this issue, It is a bugger they didn't include parenthesis by default to avoid confusion :S

Comment: You are welcome. Pity, maybe, but things like $\cos x$, $\tan t$ are standard. What they really should have done is write $1+\sin\alpha$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Indeed, that would have been far clearer. Amazing such a simple change can mean so much.

Comment: My observation comes from too many years making up questions, both for courses and contests. After one decides on the basic problem, the hard work is examining the thing symbol by symbol, looking for places where misinterpretation is *conceivable*. After all, who wants to be sued?

Answer (score 0):

As mathematics2x2life has pointed out, the quotient rule can be used.  However, I will address directly the question of what to do with
$$
\frac{d}{d\alpha} (\sin(\alpha+1))^{-1}.
$$

You can say it's $\dfrac{d}{d\alpha} u^{-1}$, so that it's
$$
\frac{d}{d\alpha} u^{-1} = (-1)u^{-2}\cdot\frac{du}{d\alpha} = -u^{-2}\cdot\frac{d}{d\alpha} \sin(\alpha+1) = \frac{-1}{u^2}\cdot\cos(\alpha+1). 
$$

After that you would multiply by $\dfrac{d}{d\alpha}(\alpha+1)$, but you'd just be multiplying by $1$, so that doesn't change anything.  Then you have
$$
\frac{-1}{(\sin(\alpha+1))^2}\cdot\cos(\alpha+1).
$$